# Android, get JSON SMS

Tags: android, json, sms

I send this `jSON` through `SMS`:

`{"l":"-3","i":"1062","od":[{"l":"-3","i":"2448"},{"l":"-4","i":"2449"}]}`

but I get this String through both `shortMessage.getMessageBody()` and `shortMessage.getDisplayMessageBody()`:

`"l":"-3","i":"1062","od":  "l":"-3","i":"2448" , "l":"-4","i":"2449"`

why `JSON` format broke and how to get the correct format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem !
The problem is about the device (in this case: **Samsung galaxy note 10.1**) 
and the solution was using special characters instead of this four characters: **`{} []`** so I replaced characters before sending SMS and then on device, replace them again. I used these characters:

`! = {
 @ = }
 # = [
 % = ]`

Answer (score 0):

Try to send like this...

"{""l":"-3","i":"1062","od":"[{""l":"-3","i":"2448""}","{""l":"-4","i":"2449""}]}"

Comment: Then i think, you have to add '/' (without quotes) before every curly and square brackets... i didnt test it... bt giv it a try...